# connection pool for proprietary connection api (non jdbc)

Tags: java, connection-pooling

I am using an API to connect to some hardware terminals and networks. The API allows me to connect to the servers, disconnect and interrogate for data, pretty similar to what JDBC connection allows you to do. Anyway, since this is not using the JDBC Connection interface, I cannot use a connection pooling already existing.
I would like to avoid writing one myself if I can use one already existing, or maybe just build a small adapter on top of that. Anyone knows of any framework/library that would allow me to enable connection pooling, that can handle my connections, can ensure that the connection is alive all the time etc?

I have looked at Commons Pool, but that only gives you a few classes to put/get your connections ... it doesn't do any of the maintenance tasks etc (check if connection is invalid from time to time, reconnect etc). I can add on top of that the mechanism of connection checking and reconnecting if any issues etc in case there is nothing out there that does this already.

Cheers, Stef.

Comment: If there isn't some bigger community around that proprietary interface then Apache Commons Pool might be your best bet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Apache Commons Pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/) actually supports creating, destroying and checking objects for validity before handing them out with the [PoolableObjectFactory](http://commons.apache.org/pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool/PoolableObjectFactory.html) class, which you use with the actual pool implementation by passing it as a parameter:

```
final PoolableObjectFactory objectFactory = new MyPoolableObjectFactoryImpl();
final ObjectPool pool = new GenericObjectPool(objectFactory);
```

Comment: Dear downvoter: As this answer actually solves the problem, maybe you could be so kind to elaborate?

Comment: Thanks Henning. I knew about that but the API that I'm using doesn't have the option to keep session alive, and was interested if the commons library has a way of regularly check the connection ... to keep it alive. Anyway, this is rather an issues with the API, so makes sense if there is no support for such in any of the libraries. I'll just use the validateObject for now and hopefully can get the other team to change and add option to keep session alive in the API.

Comment: @Stef: I see. No, keepalive is not supported, but you could possibly achieve the same outcome by evicting connections from the pool before their session dies. If this causes the pool to drop below minimum idle objects, it will just create a new connection with a fresh session and put it in the pool, thus making sure there are always fresh connections available.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into dbcp http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/

it's BasicDataSource provide methods such as maxActive, maxIdle, maxWait etc check documentation for more
http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html

interesting one if you are going for new implementation try tomcat 7 jdbc connection pool
http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html

[edit] useless for the scenario -hGx so upvoting Henning's post

Comment: The whole point of the question is that the pool does not contain JDBC connections.

Comment: i don't understand, "The whole point of the question is that the pool does not contain JDBC connections" ? isn't he mentioning about connection pooling?

Comment: The premise of the question is that he wants to pool _non-JDBC_ connections, so he won't be able to use any of the JDBC `DataSource` pools.

Comment: yeah, it was my mistake, so upvoting Henning's post